# How to get all Ldap Groups of a user including nested groups in JAVA

Tags: java, ldap

I want to find all the groups a user is part of, including nested groups.
Like if user is part of group A1 and group A1 is part of A, then I want to get A as well.

Following is code , I have tried variuos filterstrings... but nothing is given expected output.

```
String samAccountName = "group";

String searchFilter = "(&(objectclass=user)(memberof: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:="+samAccountName+"))";

//String searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=CN="+samAccountName+"))";

//String searchFilter = "(&(objectcategory=user)(memberof=CN="+samAccountName+",OU=Users,DC=new,DC=com))";

String searchBase = "DC=new,DC=com";

NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, ontrols);
             List rolesList = new ArrayList();
            while(answer.hasMoreElements()){
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
```

...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you'll have to recursively search the memberOf attribute list for a user.  e.g. if a user has the following ldif-style result from an `ldapsearch` call:

```
cn: user1
memberOf: CN=group1,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com
memberOf: CN=group2,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com
```

..then you'll want to recursively look up `group1` and `group2` with additional ldap searches, and so on for groups which those groups are membersOf.

I'm doing something similar right now, but in perl and to get flat lists of all members of all groups from Active Directory.  AD uses `objectClass: group` whereas OpenLDAP tends to use `objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames` or perhaps `objectClass: posixGroup`, depending on the use (posix groups for unix-y clients such as Linux boxes, groupOfUniqueNames groups for more general information.  It depends entirely on the clients using the information from the directory).

*Edit: In AD there is also supposed to be an attribute called `tokenGroups` which contains the SIDs of security groups for users, but this didn't work for me.  I'm guessing it's optional and not enabled on my site's AD server.*

Answer (score -1):

Below code works finding the list of groups that the user belongs to.Sun LDAP implementation is being used

```
package pack;

import static javax.naming.directory.SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

import org.acegisecurity.GrantedAuthority;
import org.acegisecurity.GrantedAuthorityImpl;

import com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory;

class App4 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String username = "userName";
    String password = "password";
    String serverName = "server";
    String domainName = "comp.BIZ";

    System.out.println("Authenticating " + username + "@" + domainName
            + " through " + serverName + "." + domainName);

    // bind by using the specified username/password
    Hashtable<String,String> props = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    String principalName = username + "@" + domainName;
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    DirContext context;

    try {
        context = LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance("ldap://" + serverName
                + "." + domainName + '/', props);
        System.out.println("Authentication succeeded!");

        // locate this user's record
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> renum = context.search(
                toDC(domainName), "(& (userPrincipalName=" + principalName
                        + ")(objectClass=user))", controls);


        if (!renum.hasMore()) 
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot locate user information for "
                    + username);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        SearchResult result = renum.next();

        List<GrantedAuthority> groups = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        Attribute memberOf = result.getAttributes().get("memberOf");
        if (memberOf != null) 
        {// null if this user belongs to no group at
                                // all
            for (int i = 0; i < memberOf.size(); i++) 
            {
                Attributes atts = context.getAttributes(memberOf.get(i)
                        .toString(), new String[] { "CN" });
                Attribute att = atts.get("CN");
                groups.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(att.get().toString()));
            }
        }

        context.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("User belongs to: ");
        Iterator<GrantedAuthority> ig = groups.iterator();
        while (ig.hasNext()) 
        {
            System.out.println("   " + ig.next().toString());
        }

    } catch (AuthenticationException a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Authentication failed: " + a);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (NamingException e) 
    {
        System.out
                .println("Failed to bind to LDAP / get account information: "
                        + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private static String toDC(String domainName) 
{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (String token : domainName.split("\\.")) 
    {
        if (token.length() == 0)
            continue; // defensive check
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(",");
        buf.append("DC=").append(token);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

String searchFilter ="(&(objectClass=person)(samaccountname="+userName+"))"

I modidfied the searchFilter and it works.

Answer (score -1):

In LDAP we can query if a User belongs to a given group once you have established a connection you can query using either member or memberOf attribute.

```
Query for memberOf Attribute : 
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=Group DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(memberOf=CN=group,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

Using member Attribute : 
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=User DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(member=CN=user,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))
```

But You'll have to search recursively using the member or memberOf attribute list for a user. e.g. if a user has the following group hierarchy :

cn: user1
memberOf: CN=group1,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com
memberOf: CN=group2,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com

then you'll want to recursively lookup group1 and group2 with additional LDAP searches, and so on for groups which those groups are members of.

Below is the sample code to query all the nested groups a User belongs to :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class MemberDemo {
    private static final String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String connectionURL = "ldap://10.224.243.133:389";
    private static final String connectionName = "CN=administrator,CN=users,DC=ppma,DC=org";
    private static final String connectionPassword = "Conleyqa12345";

    public static int nestLevel = 3;
    public static int level = 1;

    // Optional
    private static final String authentication = null;
    private static final String protocol = null;
    private static String userBase = "OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        // Configure our directory context environment.

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, connectionURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, connectionName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, connectionPassword);
        if (authentication != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
        if (protocol != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);

        InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        Set<String> traversedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> relatedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> tempParentColl = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tempGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        String loginUser = "CN=qa20Nest,OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

        String filter = "(&(member=" + loginUser + ")(objectClass=group))";
        tempGroups = findNestedGroups(tempGroups, context, filter, loginUser, constraints,
                tempParentColl, traversedGroups, getUserName(loginUser));
        relatedGroups.addAll(tempGroups);

        System.out.println("Parent Groups :");

        for (String group : relatedGroups) {
            System.out.println(group);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time taken in sec : " + elapsedTime / 1000);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List<String> findNestedGroups(List<String> tempGrpRelations, InitialDirContext context, String filter,
            String groupName, SearchControls constraints, List<String> tempParentColl, Set<String> traversedGrp,
            String groupIdentifier) {
        NamingEnumeration results;
        try {
            traversedGrp.add(groupName);
            results = context.search(userBase, filter, constraints);

            // Fail if no entries found
            if (results == null || !results.hasMore()) {
                System.out.println("No result found for :" + groupName);
                if (tempParentColl.isEmpty()) {
                    return tempGrpRelations;
                } else {
                    tempParentColl.remove(groupName);
                }
            }

            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                System.out.println("DN - " + result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempParentColl.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempGrpRelations.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
            }

            Iterator<String> itr = tempParentColl.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String groupDn = itr.next();
                String nfilter = "(&(member=" + groupDn + ")(objectClass=group))";
                tempParentColl.remove(groupDn);
                if (!traversedGrp.contains(groupDn)) {
                    findNestedGroups(tempGrpRelations, context, nfilter, groupDn, constraints, tempParentColl,
                            traversedGrp, getUserName(groupDn));
                }
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempGrpRelations;
    }

    public static String getUserName(String cnName) {

        String name = cnName.substring(cnName.indexOf("CN=")).split(",")[0].split("=")[1];
        return name;
    }
}
```